# Using the detection idiom to determine whether a type has a constructor with a specific signature

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm playing with the [proposal of standard library support for the C++ detection idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf). It is a trait-like metafunction that determines whether a type `T` has a type member named `T::type` or a member function with a specific signature, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>


template<class...>
using void_t = void;

template<class, template<class> class, class = void_t<>>
struct detect : std::false_type { };

template<class T, template<class> class Operation>
struct detect<T, Operation, void_t<Operation<T>>> : std::true_type { };


template<class T>
using bar_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar());

template<class T>
using bar_int_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(0));

template<class T>
using bar_string_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(""));


struct foo
{
    int bar() { return 0; }
    int bar(int) { return 0; }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << detect<foo, bar_t>{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << detect<foo, bar_int_t>{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << detect<foo, bar_string_t>{} << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code above yields the expected output

```
1
1
0
```

You can play with a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2265919c09a2379e). Now, I would like to test if a type `T` has a constructor with a specific signature, e.g. `T::T(U)` with another type `U`. Is it possible to do that using the detection idiom?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::is_constructible`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the `detect` class to allow for variadic args:

```
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename AlwaysVoid, template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
struct detect_impl : std::false_type { };

template <template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
struct detect_impl<void_t<Operation<Args...>>, Operation, Args...> : std::true_type { };
```

Add an alias that hard-codes a void type:

```
template <template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
using detect = detect_impl<void, Operation, Args...>;
//                         ~~~^
```

Write a detector:

```
template <typename T, typename... Us>
using has_constructor = decltype(T(std::declval<Us>()...));
```

Test your class:

```
static_assert(detect<has_constructor, foo, foo>{}, "!");
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b41ab1dd05e240f6)

Answer (score 2):

Even better: [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)

---

```
template<class U>
struct constructable_from {
  template<class T>
  using test_t = decltype(T(std::declval<U>()));
};

// usage
detect<foo, constructable_from<baz>::test_t> {}
```

This seems to be working with your code. One can easily extend this to support multi parameter constructors using variadic templates. I don't know whether this is "using the detection idiom", but it's what I've been using myself sometime ago.

My [test code on ideone](http://ideone.com/Skdtu2) (it's a bit messy, I'm on mobile)