# Check if a template specialization of a method exists

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

Let's say I have a template class like this:

```
template<typename TRequest, typename TResponse = void>
class handler
{
private:
    static void validate_core(const TRequest& request);
    static TResponse process_core(const TRequest& request);
public:
    static TResponse process(const TRequest& request)
    {
        if (validate_core is implemented)
        {
            log("begin validate");
            validate_core(request);
        }

        return process_core(request);
    }
};
```

`process_core` has to be implemented for different TRequest/TResponse types, while `validate_core` is optional, I want to invoke it if it's implemented.

Currently my workaround is giving a default empty implementation to `validate_core`, if it's not specialized then an empty method is invoked. I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the detection idiom to determine whether a type has a constructor with a specific signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669304/using-the-detection-idiom-to-determine-whether-a-type-has-a-constructor-with-a-s)

Comment: The linked dupe is ever so slightly different, as is the case for detection idioms, but you should be able to work it out.

Comment: @PasserBy For normal methods I saw a few solutions, however they are not suitable for template methods.

Comment: You might want to show what you did and failed.

Comment: boost::hana has the costexpr_if and is_valid consructs. That should solve it in a reasonably readable way. c++17 has constexpr if which makes the switch prettier.

Comment: @DannyChen What isn't suitable for what? You just need to check if a hypothetical call to `validate_core` with a `TRequest` is viable. The detection idiom can do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently my workaround is giving a default empty implementation to validate_core, if it's not specialized then an empty method is invoked. I want to know if there is a better way.

It seems to me a very good way.

Not sure to understand your requirements but I suppose you could delete the template version of `validate_core()`

```
  template <typename TRq = TRequest>
  static void validate_core (TRequest const &) = delete;
```

and enable, inside the body of `handler`, one ore more non-template specializations

```
  static void validate_core (int const &)
   { /* do something */ }

  static void validate_core (long const &)
   { /* do something */ }

  // ...
```

Next you could add, in the body of `handler`, a type traits to detect if it's available a specialization for `validate_core()`

```
  template <typename, typename = void>
  struct withValidateCore : public std::false_type
   { };

  template <typename T>
  struct withValidateCore<T, decltype(validate_core(std::declval<T>()))>
     : public std::true_type
   { };
```

If you could use C++17, this way could be interesting because it's available `if constexpr ()`, so should be possible something as [sorry: not tested]

```
static TResponse process (TRequest const & request)
 {
   if constexpr ( withValidateCore<TRequest>::value )
    {
       log("begin validate");
       validate_core(request);
    }

   return process_core(request);
 }
```

But you tagged C++14, so `if constexpr ()` isn't available and the best way I see to use `withValidateCore` is implement two different (SFINAE enabled/disabled) versions of `process()`; something like

```
  template <typename TRq = TRequest>
  static std::enable_if_t<(true == withValidateCore<TRq>{})
        && (true == std::is_same<TRq, TRequest>{}), TResponse>
     process (TRequest const & request)
   {
     validate_core(request);

     return process_core(request);
   }

  template <typename TRq = TRequest>
  static std::enable_if_t<(false == withValidateCore<TRq>{})
        && (true == std::is_same<TRq, TRequest>{}), TResponse>
     process (TRequest const & request)
   { return process_core(request); }
```

Otherwise (maybe a little better) something tag-dispatching based

```
private:
   static TResponse process (TRequest const & request,
                             std::true_type const &)
    {
      validate_core(request);

      return process_core(request);
    }

   static TResponse process (TRequest const & request,
                             std::false_type const &)
    { return process_core(request); }

public:
   static TResponse process (TRequest const & request)
    { return process(request, withValidateCore<TRequest>{}); }
```

IMHO it's better (in C++14) the solution based on a empty generic version of `validate_core()`.

Anyway, the following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename TRequest, typename TResponse = void>
class handler
 {
   private:
      template <typename TRq = TRequest>
      static void validate_core (TRequest const &) = delete;

      static void validate_core (int const &)
       { std::cout << "- validate_core() int case" << std::endl; }

      static void validate_core (long const &)
       { std::cout << "- validate_core() long case" << std::endl; }

      static TResponse process_core (const TRequest &)
       { return TResponse(); }

      template <typename, typename = void>
      struct withValidateCore : public std::false_type
       { };

      template <typename T>
      struct withValidateCore<T, decltype(validate_core(std::declval<T>()))>
         : public std::true_type
       { };

   public:
      template <typename TRq = TRequest>
      static std::enable_if_t<(true == withValidateCore<TRq>{})
            && (true == std::is_same<TRq, TRequest>{}), TResponse>
         process (TRequest const & request)
       {
         validate_core(request);

         return process_core(request);
       }

      template <typename TRq = TRequest>
      static std::enable_if_t<(false == withValidateCore<TRq>{})
            && (true == std::is_same<TRq, TRequest>{}), TResponse>
         process (TRequest const & request)
       { return process_core(request); }
 };

int main()
 {
   handler<int>::process(0);        // print - validate_core() int case
   handler<int, long>::process(0);  // print - validate_core() int case
   handler<long>::process(0);       // print - validate_core() long case
   handler<char>::process(0);       // no print
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check at compile time if a template specialization is implemented. At best you can generate a link-time error by declaring and extern template instantiation.

I have understood that you want that `process` implements the so-called *template method design pattern*. If this is the case, you may find the below use of CRTP interesting. (Nota bene: I have modified function signature to make this code compilable)

```
template<class Derived, typename TRequest, typename TResponse>
class handler_base
{
private:
//caution trickery
static constexpr bool validate_core=false;

public:
static TResponse* process(const TRequest& request)
  {
    if constexpr (Derived::validate_core)
    {
        //log("begin validate");
        Derived::validate_core(request);
    }

    return Derived::process_core(request);
  }
};

template<typename TRequest, typename TResponse=void>
class handler;

class Req1;
class Req2;
class Resp1;
class Resp2;

template<>
class handler<Req1,Resp1>
  : handler_base<handler<Req1,Resp1>,Req1,Resp1>
  {
  static void validate_core(const Req1& request);
  static Resp1* process_core(const Req1& request);
  friend handler_base;
  };

 template<>
 class handler<Req2,Resp2>
  : handler_base<handler<Req2,Resp2>,Req2,Resp2>
  {
  friend handler_base;
  static Resp2* process_core(const Req2& request);
  };
//just to force compilation
template Resp2* handler_base<handler<Req2,Resp2>,Req2,Resp2>::process(const Req2&);
template Resp1* handler_base<handler<Req1,Resp1>,Req1,Resp1>::process(const Req1&);
```